# Is the expression "most number of participants" correct?

Tags: grammaticality, meaning-in-context

Which is correct—"most number of participants" or "highest number of  participants"?

In a conference, an award was given to a group that has the largest number of participants. The title of the award is "Most Number of Participants". How can the title be phrased better?

Comment: Can you give some context?

Comment: Most participants.  Greatest number of participants.

Comment: Why not just "the most participants"?

Answer (score 3):

I have never heard `"most number of participants"`. "Most" means "the largest number" so I think it's incorrect to use it this way.

"The highest number of participants" is not grammatically wrong, but again it sounds awkward to me. You can use **"the largest number of participants"** or 
**"the greatest number of participants"**.

Comment: [Example of "most number of ..." both spoken and written](https://youtu.be/4hTBRTRvQSo?t=278)